# Socket.io wont emit events in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I'm starting to code with AngularJS and I'm trying to create a real time app with Socket.io:

I'm using a service, console show that connection seems fine.

[Console.log picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai9JL.png)

But, when I try to emit code from frontend to backend, nothing happens.

This is a ***copy of the backend*** :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server, {
    transport: ['polling'],
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
      }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected with id ' + socket.id);
  
  socket.on('test', () => {
    console.log("testing emitting")
  })
  socket.on('getRed', function () {
    socket.send("red");
    console.log("Requested change color")
  })
  socket.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Socket.IO Error happened");
    console.log(); 
  });

});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

My ***App.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SocketIoConfig, SocketIoModule } from 'ngx-socket-io';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { NgxChatService } from './ngx-chat.service';


const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js', options: {}}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ChatComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  providers: [NgxChatService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The Service **NgxChat.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket} from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgxChatService implements OnInit {
  constructor(private socket: Socket) {}
  
  public emitHello = () => {
    this.socket.ioSocket.io.emit('test');
    this.socket.emit('test');
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.emitHello();
  }

}
```

Version is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^4.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
}
```

Somebody has any clue of what could is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this error, the tutorial that I was following was wrong in the instructions to do the call. It was necessary to change this.

```
import { Injectable, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import  SocketClient  from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketWebService implements OnInit {
  constructor() { 
    this.emitHello();
    this.io.on('distribution', (value : any) => {
        (this.io.id === value.id )? "local" : "remoto";

        if (this.io.id === value.id) {
          this.log_local.push({
            value: value.value,
            id: "local",
            userCreator: value.userCreator,
            userAvatar: value.userAvatar
          });
        } else {
          this.log_local.push({
            value: value.value,
            id: "remote",
            userCreator: value.userCreator,
            userAvatar: value.userAvatar
          });
        }
    })
  }

@Input() io = SocketClient('http://localhost:3000', { 
  autoConnect: true
})
@Input() log_local : any = [];
  public emitHello = () => {
    this.io.emit('test')
  }
  public emitMessage = (msg : String, user : any) => {
    console.log(user)
    this.io.emit('message', {
      msg,
      user
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

To be clear:

```
@Input() io = SocketClient('http://localhost:3000', { 
  autoConnect: true
})
```

And checking that both versions was the same, did the fix.